# -mmacosx-version-min influences packing behaviour with bitfields?

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I'm seeing an odd behaviour where my bitfields are ended up in the padding:

```
 struct Test {
     unsigned short a : 1;
     unsigned short b : 15;
 };
```

when compiled with `-mmacosx-version-min=10.11` (or greater) in clang (tested 4.0.1 and Apple's 10.0.0), I get in https://github.com/arvidn/struct_layout:

```
struct ::Test [2 Bytes]
   --- 2 Bytes padding ---
```

with `-mmacosx-version-min=10.10` (or lower) I get:

```
struct ::Test [2 Bytes]
    0: [unsigned short : 2] a                             -- {cache-line 0}
    0: [unsigned short : 2] b
```

Anyone have any ideas what standard or rule I've violated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `struct_layout` tool you're using relies on DWARF debugging information. The differences you're seeing do not reflect a difference in data layout, only in the available debugging info.

Using `-mmacosx-version-min=10.10` limits the version of DWARF used to version 2, because that's all that macOS 10.10's tools will understand. I expect that you would get similar results by specifying `-gdwarf-2`.

Comment: Thanks, LLDB from VS Code was giving me the same issues, but it's probably because due to an older version of it being packaged with its C++ extensions.